# Zabbix обрезает текст в подписе на Карте

Tags: сеть, карты, zabbix, мониторинг

Подскажите пожалуйста Zabbix обрезает текст выводимый в подписи на карте до 19 символов и потом ставит троеточие ( обрезает)

к примеру в подписи стоит вывести температуру ( это как пример, знаю что таких значений нет ): Пример подписи :
**В стойке  {SENSORS:temp1.last()}
Вход температура : {SENSORS:vhod_temp.last()}**

и если значение temp1 или vhod_temp будет больше 19 символов то он напишет:
 Вход температура :12345678912345678...
 **а надо Вход температура :12345678912345678910111213**

проблема вывести длинный ФИО сотрудников в подписи, есть больше 19 символов и в подписи получается **DOMEN\vasiliy.pupki...**

**хотя в самих данных: DOMEN\vasiliy.pupkinchenko**

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=57714

Comment: Может просто вы за границы карты выходите? У меня такой проблемы не наблюдается.